# Flash - Only show message on load if user is not already over the movie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouseevent

I have a flash movie, that shows a message to a user when it first loads up. When the users mouse enters the stage or moves the mouse the message disappears. However I would like to hide the message if the users mouse starts over the flash movie on the page load. Is this possible or does it need an interaction first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Rectangle object that has the same `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` values as the stage's. Then you create a condition(if statement) that checks to see if the `Rectangle` object contains the stage's `mouseX` and `mouseY` values upon initiation of your application. The following is a simple test to this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var textField:TextField = new TextField();
            addChild(textField);

            var stageRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(stage.x, stage.y, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);

            if (stageRect.contains(stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY))
            {
                textField.text = "mouse is inside stage upon initiation";

            }
            else
            {
                textField.text = "mouse is outside stage upon initiation";

            }// end if

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply but this doesn't seem to work once I embed it into a webpage, even using your example above. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you probably need to set the focus of the flash first using javascript or jquery to be sure it will read the mouse when it has loaded.